# Google Cloud Storage API Settings gives me Failed to load

Tags: angularjs, cordova, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to use the `Google Cloud Storage API` from `angular` uploading some files. I've craeted a browser key on the **API & Credentials** console menu. But when I perform a GET on the URL `https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/[PROJECT_ID].appspot.com/o?key=[API_KEY]`, I receive this

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
    "message": "Access Not Configured. The API (Cloud Storage API) is not enabled for your project. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your configuration.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://console.developers.google.com"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Access Not Configured. The API (Cloud Storage API) is not enabled for your project. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your configuration."
 }
}
```

When I go to the Google's console to configure that on the `Storage` > `Cloud Storage` > `Storage settings` it gives me this error at the top of the page

[image]

**Can anybody help me on this goal?** It is important to me that the API is consumed from the font-end only, because it is a `Apache Cordova` app with angular, trying to upload files (Media) to the Cloud.

Comment: thanks for the report. We're looking into it. In the meantime, you could try to use the old console https://code.google.com/apis/console/b/0/?noredirect to make the changes you need.

Comment: Thanks for the link, and the response. I've activated the GCS API on the console (http://grab.by/I7We), then I created a **Key for browser applications**, and that's the key that I'm trying to use, but It keeps throwing the same response `Access Not Configured. The API (Cloud Storage API) is not enabled for your project. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your configuration.` (I'm trying to use this without https, is mandatory to use https? If thats the case my project is ruin xD)

Comment: Maybe if I tell you what I want to do, then you can help me better (I know nothing like john sn... you know) I've got only front-end users, they are not authenticated with Google Account (and they will not be), and I need to allow them to upload public content to a bucket, so my `angular` app (running in the `cordova` thing) it's gonna perform the upload. Am I too wrong on the idea? (also no https) =P

Comment: You'll need to enable the Cloud Storage API here: https://console.developers.google.com/project/_/apiui/apiview/storage_component/overview